# Is it always true that $f$ is continuous at $c$ given the following conditions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $F(x)$ is an indefinite integral of $f(x)$, and is also differentiable at $c$ in the interval $I=[a,b]$, with $a<b$.

Is it always true that $f$ is continuous at $c$?

I know from the fundamental theorem that if $f$ is continuous, then $F(x)$ is differentiable, however I'm not quite sure with the converse.

If it's not always true, could you show a counter example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counter-example. Let $f(0)=0,f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ and consider the indefinite integral $$F(x) =\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$ It can be proved with some effort that $F'(x) =f(x) $ for all $x$, but $f$ is discontinuous at $0$.

And yes you are right about the converse of FTC. Continuity of $f$ at $c$ is only a sufficient but not necessary condition for the equation $F'(c) =f(c) $. What is known however is that if $f$ has a simple discontinuity at $c$ then $F'(c) $ does not exist. More precisely left hand derivative of $F$ at $c$ is equal to the left hand limit of $f$ at $c$ and similar statement holds for right hand derivative.